# Having jQuery insert defined content

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, navigation

I have a navigation menu in xHTML with the following typical structure:

```
<ul id="nav1">
<li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have this jQuery script to add a space and a slash after every link:

```
$('#nav1 li,#nav2 li').append('&nbsp;/');
```

However, after the last link (aka the last li), I want to only add a space (aka &nbsp). I tried doing this, but it didn't get the job done:

```
$('#nav1 li,#nav2 li').append('&nbsp;/').filter('#nav1 li:last,#nav2 li:last').append('&nbsp;');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks! Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I think something like this should get the work done:

```
$('#nav1 li,#nav2 li').not(":last").append('&nbsp;/').end().last().append('&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#nav1 li:not(:last),#nav2 li:not(:last)').append('&nbsp;/');
$('#nav1 li:last,#nav2 li:last').append('&nbsp;');
```